# merge two dataset which are having different column names in Apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We need to merge two dataset which are having different column names, there are no common columns across the datasets.

We have tried couple of approaches, both of the approaches are not yielding result. Kindly let us know how to combine two dataset using Apache spark Java

Input data set 1

```
"405-048011-62815", "CRC Industries",

"630-0746","Dixon value",

"4444-444","3M INdustries",

"555-55","Dixon coupling valve"
```

Input dataset 2

```
"222-2222-5555", "Tata",

"7777-88886","WestSide",

"22222-22224","Reliance",

"33333-3333","V industries"
```

Expected out is

```
    ----------label1----|------sentence1------|------label2---|------sentence2-----------
    | 405-048011-62815  | CRC Industries      | 222-2222-5555 |                      Tata|
    |        630-0746   |   Dixon value       |   7777-88886  |                  WestSide|
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`

```
    List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                    RowFactory.create("405-048011-62815", "CRC Industries"),
                    RowFactory.create("630-0746","Dixon value"),
                    RowFactory.create("4444-444","3M INdustries"),
                    RowFactory.create("555-55","Dixon coupling valve"));

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {new StructField("label1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("sentence1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()) });

    Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

    List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    listStrings.add("405-048011-62815");
    listStrings.add("630-0746");

    Dataset<Row> matchFound1=sentenceDataFrame.filter(col("label1").isin(listStrings.stream().toArray(String[]::new)));
    matchFound1.show();
    listStrings.clear();
    listStrings.add("222-2222-5555");
    listStrings.add("7777-88886");

    List<Row> data2 = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create("222-2222-5555", "Tata"),
            RowFactory.create("7777-88886","WestSide"),
            RowFactory.create("22222-22224","Reliance"),
            RowFactory.create("33333-3333","V industries"));

    StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {new StructField("label2", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("sentence2", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()) });

    Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2);

    Dataset<Row> matchFound2=sentenceDataFrame2.filter(col("label2").isin(listStrings.stream().toArray(String[]::new)));
    matchFound2.show();

    //Approach 1
    Dataset<Row> matchFound3=matchFound1.select(matchFound1.col("label1"),matchFound1.col("sentence1"),matchFound2.col("label2"),
            matchFound2.col("sentence2"));
    System.out.println("After concat");
    matchFound3.show();

    //Approach 2
    Dataset<Row> matchFound4=matchFound1.filter(concat((col("label1")),matchFound1.col("sentence1"),matchFound2.col("label2"),
            matchFound2.col("sentence2")));
    System.out.println("After concat 2");
    matchFound4.show();`
```

Error for each of the approaches are as follows

Approach 1 error

```
----------
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) label2#10,sentence2#11 missing from label1#0,sentence1#1 in operator !Project [label1#0, sentence1#1, label2#10, sentence2#11];;
!Project [label1#0, sentence1#1, label2#10, sentence2#11]
+- Filter label1#0 IN (405-048011-62815,630-0746)
   +- LocalRelation [label1#0, sentence1#1]


----------
Error for each of the approaches are as follows
Approach 2 error
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: filter expression 'concat(`label1`, `sentence1`, `label2`, `sentence2`)' of type string is not a boolean.;;
!Filter concat(label1#0, sentence1#1, label2#10, sentence2#11)
+- Filter label1#0 IN (405-048011-62815,630-0746)
   +- LocalRelation [label1#0, sentence1#1]
```

Answer (score 5):

hope this work for you

**DF**

```
val pre: Array[String] = Array("CRC Industries", "Dixon value" ,"3M INdustries" ,"Dixon coupling valve")
        val rea: Array[String] = Array("405048011-62815", "630-0746", "4444-444", "555-55")
        val df1 = sc.parallelize( rea zip pre).toDF("label1","sentence1")

        val preasons2: Array[String] = Array("Tata", "WestSide","Reliance", "V industries")
         val reasonsI2: Array[String] = Array( "222-2222-5555", "7777-88886", "22222-22224", "33333-3333")
        val df2 = sc.parallelize( reasonsI2 zip preasons2 ).toDF("label2","sentence2")
```

**String Indexer**

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

```
val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label1")
  .setOutputCol("label1Index")

val indexed = indexer.fit(df1).transform(df1)
indexed.show()

val indexer1 = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label2")
  .setOutputCol("label2Index")

val indexed1 = indexer1.fit(df2).transform(df2)
indexed1.show()
```

**Join**

```
    val rnd_reslt12 = indexed.join(indexed1 , indexed.col("label1Index")===indexed1.col("label2Index")).drop(indexed.col("label1Index")).drop(indexed1.col("label2Index"))
rnd_reslt12.show()

+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|         label1|           sentence1|       label2|   sentence2|
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|       630-0746|         Dixon value|222-2222-5555|        Tata|
|       4444-444|       3M INdustries|  22222-22224|    Reliance|
|         555-55|Dixon coupling valve|   33333-3333|V industries|
|405048011-62815|      CRC Industries|   7777-88886|    WestSide|
+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: As I have mentioned there is no common column, so we can't use df_reason1.col("id")===df_reason2.col("code")

Comment: you can create index apply this to each dataframe and then perform join

Comment: check now this is what you want

Answer (score 4):

With string indexer i have done with java, this will work.

```
public class StringIndexer11  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dataset<Row> csvDataSet=null;
        try{
            System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\AI matching\\winutil");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
            SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();
            List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                    RowFactory.create("405-048011-62815", "CRC Industries"),
                    RowFactory.create("630-0746","Dixon value"),
                    RowFactory.create("4444-444","3M INdustries"),
                    RowFactory.create("555-55","Dixon coupling valve"));

            StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {new StructField("label1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("sentence1", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()) });

            Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

            List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
            listStrings.add("405-048011-62815");
            listStrings.add("630-0746");
             Dataset<Row> matchFound1=sentenceDataFrame.filter(col("label1").isin(listStrings.stream().toArray(String[]::new)));
            matchFound1.show();
            listStrings.clear();
            listStrings.add("222-2222-5555");
            listStrings.add("7777-88886");

            StringIndexer indexer = new StringIndexer()
              .setInputCol("label1")
              .setOutputCol("label1Index");
            Dataset<Row> Dataset1 = indexer.fit(matchFound1).transform(matchFound1);
            //Dataset1.show();


            List<Row> data2 = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create("222-2222-5555", "Tata"),
            RowFactory.create("7777-88886","WestSide"),
            RowFactory.create("22222-22224","Reliance"),
            RowFactory.create("33333-3333","V industries"));

            StructType schema2 = new StructType(new StructField[] {new StructField("label2", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("sentence2", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty()) });

            Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, schema2);

            Dataset<Row> matchFound2=sentenceDataFrame2.filter(col("label2").isin(listStrings.stream().toArray(String[]::new)));
            matchFound2.show();

            StringIndexer indexer1 = new StringIndexer()
              .setInputCol("label2")
              .setOutputCol("label2Index");
            Dataset<Row> Dataset2 = indexer1.fit(matchFound2).transform(matchFound2);
            //Dataset2.show();
            Dataset<Row> Finalresult = Dataset1.join(Dataset2 , Dataset1.col("label1Index").equalTo(Dataset2.col("label2Index"))).drop(Dataset1.col("label1Index")).drop(Dataset2.col("label2Index"));
                    Finalresult.show();


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```